# hacked from metamask wallet

Tags: metamask, security

yesterday 2.3.2021 at 18:25 i was hacked. they stole all my founds from metamusk wallet from my address 0xeD14989682D3770AC0a9AEB2608Aa2315cF312Df and took everything to this address 0x963904bf5962c7D7c9aE1F145B6b609Df848F4A4. Some of crypto is still there.

was reporting yesterday to etherium.io, metamusk, even report a scam but 10 hours later nobody did nothing. how can i get my crypto back.

- SHIBA INU 50173B
- SWISSBORG 900
- POLKASTARTER POLS 100
- TELCOIN 551,513
- ETH 1.1

Comment: sorry for your loss, but they can't do anything. So don't use it anymore, move all coins if you still have some and try to find out how the "hacker" got your seed or private keys. the hardware wallet is the best place to store your crypto

Comment: Again, sorry to hear this. As @MajdTL says, the funds can't be taken back. A few questions: Where did you download Metamask from? Did you use Metamask to create the wallet/private key, or did you import it from somewhere else? Where did you keep the backup of your seed phrase? Have you granted permissions to any Dapps?

Comment: been using @Metamask for quite a time. wallet and seed are on paper. don t know how but they did it, i do have address and I did report to many institutions but as I see on twitter i m not alone. nothing more to tell just a few 10000 times ?MetaMusk

Comment: I'm sorry to hear all that. Where did you download your Metamask extension from?